# Getting Data from PHP to work in HTML

Tags: php, ajax

I have tried many things but none have been successful.  I am trying to get the Rating option to change after the box (Select to Pull Asset Center Data) is selected. It gets the data in the php file but I have no idea how to work with the data in the html file.

Data
servername  contact classification  rating
Server1 Ray Production  A
Server2 Eric    Non-Production  B

> --
>
> ### -- Database: `ipreservation`
>
> ---
>
> --
>
> ### -- Table structure for table `acdata`
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acdata` (
>   `servername` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
>   `contact` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
>   `classification` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   `rating` varchar(4) NOT NULL 
> ) 
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
> CHARSET=latin1;
> ```
>
> --
>
> ### -- Dumping data for table `acdata`
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `acdata` (`servername`, `contact`, `classification`,`rating`) 
> VALUES ('Server1', 'Ray', 'Production', 'A'),
> ('Server2','Eric', 'Non-Production', 'B');
> ```
>
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

servertest.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showServer(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
var server = document.getElementById('existingserver').value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","servertest.php?q="+server,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<label>Existing Server</label><input type="text" name="existingserver" id="textfield" maxlength="15"/>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showServer(this.value)" >Select to Pull Asset Center Data<br>
<br />
<br />
Rating
<select name="rating" id="rating">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />

<div id="txtHint"><b>Server info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

servertest.php

> `$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'assignip', 'assignip');
> if (!$con) {
>    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
> }` 
>
>   
>   mysql_select_db("ipreservation", $con);
>   
>   $sql = "SELECT * FROM acdata WHERE servername = '".$q."'";
>   
>   $result = mysql_query($sql);
>   
>   echo "  Servername Contact
>   Classification Rating ";
>
> ```
> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {
>     echo "<tr>";
>         echo "<td>" . $row['servername'] . "</td>";
>         echo "<td>" . $row['contact']. "</td>";
>         echo "<td>" . $row['classification'] . "</td>";
>         echo "<td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
>     echo "</tr>";   
> } 
> echo "</table>";
> ```
>
> mysql_close($con); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your code simplified with jQuery and working, find below your updated code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var id = $('#existingserver').val();            
            $('#assetCenter').click(function(){
                var id = $('#textfield').val();
                $.get('servertest.php',{q:id}, function(htmlData){
                    $('#txtHint').html(htmlData);                    
                    $('#rating').val(htmlData); 
                });
            });
        });    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <label>Existing Server</label><input type="text" name="existingserver" id="textfield" maxlength="15"/>

            <input type="checkbox" id="assetCenter" onclick="showServer(this.value)" >Select to Pull Asset Center Data<br>
            <br />
            <br />
            Rating
            <select name="rating" id="rating">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br />

        <div id="txtHint"><b>Server info will be listed here.</b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with jquery but it is definitely something I need to start learning starting tomorrow.  My goal is to have the option for the rating changed depending on what the value is in the db. Also, I am getting an error since showserver is not defined now.

Comment: copy paste my code and check it is working as you wanted. jQuery is very simple to use and it really saves hours coding.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I have tried this on 2 systems and different browsers and I am still not geting the option of the rating to switch.  I am using firefox with firebug and the error it is showing is that showServer is not defined.  That was the function I was calling when the box was clicked. Can you please explain how that gets used with your code?

Comment: in your <input type="text" name="existingserver" id="textfield" maxlength="15"/>  change its id to existingserver like this "<input type="text" name="existingserver" id="existingserver" maxlength="15"/>" as you are using var server = document.getElementById('existingserver').value; and that is coming out null, when do you want your rating to switch? how you want your functionality to flow

Comment: User enters servname: example 'server2'
user checks box Select to Pull Asset Center Data
Rating switches immediately to A,B,C, or D depending on info in db: example server 2 would switch it to B

Comment: its simple if you send json data from your servertest.php file then you can easily use that data to change the value of your dropdown. use like this store your $row in loop in $data[] array, and outside of loop write "echo json_encode($data);"  give me the out put of this and I'll update my answer with the result

Comment: check the updated code, if your result is "B" it will work perfectely, but if you want to do much more that that then you can use json_encode($data); it will give output like ["B"] or may combination of {} and [], Please add alert() in callback function and print the output, when we get json then only we can convert in to proper js object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20475/discussion-between-ray-hebert-and-pankaj-khairnar)